# Virtual Pageviews reduce bounce rate and increase pages per session

Tags: google, google-analytics, pagerank

I add virtual pageviews on my javascript part of website,
I see good results, reduce bounce rate, increase pages per session,
but don't know this worth I mean, google count that and this affect on my page rank?

e.g.

`class="more-button" 
               onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'More', 'click', 'Front Page'); 
                        ga('send', 'pageview', location.pathname + '/More');">
 More
</a>`

Comment: I do not know what you mean buy *virtual pageviews*. Can you explain this more?? Cheers!!

Comment: @closetnoc I edit question, please check

Comment: @closetnoc, a virtual pageview is a pageview hit that is sent to represent a change in content on a page, which is not accompanied by a change in the URL. For example, if you have a modal window that opens on a page, it would make sense to send a "virtual" pageview for that modal to track that it was seen. I don't think virtual pageviews have any bearing on page ranks.

Comment: @nyuen *I don't think virtual pageviews have any bearing on page ranks.* I agree! GA has nothing to do with search performance. Otherwise, everyone would write JS code to influence search. So the answer to the OPs question is No. No they will not help page rank. Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

Just to summarise the little discussion @closetnoc and I had, we both believe that virtual pageviews will not affect your search page ranking. Your GA data and search performance are two separate things that are mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 1):

Data gathered by Google Analytics has no direct impact on your site's performance in the organic index, so, in general, you don't have to worry about this. There is one case of GA usage however, that can make things tricky - it's called Content Experiments. Rule of thumb is to always have canonical tags properly set up.

Regarding virtual page views - I recommend switching to [events](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033068?hl=en) instead of virtual page views. As you noted in your question, each page view always provides a timestamp from which GA can calculate bounce rate and time on site/page, but this is not always a good thing. While using events, you can specify whether you wish a particular event to be treated by GA as interaction or non-interaction event. Please see the "Non-Interaction Events" section on the linked events doc page.

To give you full picture - there is also a way to stick with virtual page views if you really want to (from whatever reason). In such case, I recommend creating another property within your GA account. Use this property for virtual page views - in this way GA will gather interaction data but will not skew metrics such as bounce rate, time on site and so forth. Just remember that you need to [tweak GA tracking code](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/creating-trackers#working_with_multiple_trackers) in order for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

All you are doing is artificially inflating your stats. Your bounce rate hasn't improved, you've just completely skewed the data.

It will have absolutely no effect on your page rank or positioning in serps, all you've done is made your data difficult to understand.

Answer (score -2):

virtual page increase the traffic but reduces the page rank

Comment: One line answers are not high quality.  Answers here are expected to explain more.  Please edit your answer and explain "why".   You can add personal experience that illustrates your answer or you can find links to documentation and references.

Comment: Your answer is also not correct.  Google PageRank is a measure that Google uses to determine the reputation of pages.   It doesn't use traffic.  It uses links.   If you are talking about rankings in Google search, Google has said they don't use Google Analytics data to determine those either.